# Hiding Keyboard in xcode storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios

New to xcode,i'm creating a simple login form in xcode 4.2 and i would like to hide the keyboard,i have the correct code i think,from the tutorial it says i need to change the class of the view to UIControl but there is no option for this, is there another way when working with storyboards?

```
- (IBAction)backGroundTouched:(id)sender
{
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [passTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: The code here should hide the keyboard. Can you post a link to the tutorial you are looking at?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are doing them inside the viewCotroller, invoke

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you - this saved me a fair bit of typing. =)

Answer (score 2):

If your two text fields are subviews of some higher-level view you can also use `[higherLevelView endEditing];` and not care which subview is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure your both text fields is connect with it's IBOutlets.
No need to change UIView to UIControl.

// Connect every textfield's "Did end on exit" event with this method.
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];


}

// Use this method also if you want to hide keyboard when user touch in background

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [passTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_7_Code_to_Hide_the_Keyboard and it's working for me:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([_textField isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _textField) {
        [_textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```